Why is my chatbot reloading from firebase every time data in firebase updates?
I am trying to minimise the unnecessary data sent to and from firebase by my chatbot. It is correctly syncing across devices, however, it is loading the entire state to every device every time the data is updated, including the device that triggered the update (and therefore already contains all the state data being loaded).
The weird this is that due to console logs I know that loadGroupData is being called, but the only time that this function is mentioned in my code is in this function, and the console never logs "Loading group state for:", savedCurrentGroup) apart from on the initial load:
function loadGroupState(savedCurrentGroup) {
  // Log the group being loaded
  console.log("Loading group state for:", savedCurrentGroup);

  // Reference to the group in Firebase
  const groupRef = ref(db, `groups/${String(savedCurrentGroup)}`);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      onValue(groupRef, (snapshot) => {
          const groupData = snapshot.val();
          if (groupData) {
              // If group data exists, load it into the chatbot state
              document.getElementById("initialContainer").style.display = "none";
              **loadGroupData(groupData)**; // Call a separate function to load the data
              
              resolve(groupData); // Resolve the promise
              updateFlag();
              
          } else {
              // No data found, initialize default state instead of rejecting
              console.log("No data found for this group. Initializing default state.");
              const defaultGroupData = {
                  stage: 0,
                  navyStage: 0,
                  userName: 'You',
                  currentClueIndex: 0,
                  penaltyPoints: 0,
                  navySupported: false,
                  accessible: false,
                  navyReminderSent: 0,
                  totalPausedTime: 0,
                  pauseStartTime: 0,
                  startTime: 0,
                  userNumber: 1,
                  hintsRequested: 0,
                  currentGroup: savedCurrentGroup,
                  navyDeceived: false,
                  typingmessage: false,
              };

              // Load the default group state
              loadGroupData(defaultGroupData);
              resolve(defaultGroupData); // Resolve with default data instead of rejecting
              saveStateAndLog();
          }
      }, (error) => {
          reject(error); // Reject the promise on error
      });
  });
}

How is this possible?
I am pretty new to coding so I might be doing something obvious wrong.
I tried adding code to suppress local updates on the event listeners, but this is not working. The console logs 'update suppressed' but the chatbot still does the unnecessary loading.

function listenForChanges() {
  const groupRef = ref(db, `groups/${currentGroup}`);
  

  // Attach listeners for real-time updates after the initial load
  onValue(child(groupRef, 'chatLog'), (snapshot) => {
      if (suppressLocalUpdates){
         console.log ('update suppressed');

         return; }// Ignore if this instance caused the update
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
          chatLog.innerHTML = snapshot.val() || '';
      }
  });

  onValue(child(groupRef, 'stage'), (snapshot) => {
    if (suppressLocalUpdates){
      console.log ('update suppressed');

      return; }
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
          stage = snapshot.val() || 0;
      }
  });


etc.

The onValue callback always gets called with a full snapshot of the data at the location you call it with. Even if only a single child was changed or added, the snapshot for onValue always contains all data at the path.
If you only want to hear about the exact change that was made, you want to use the onChild... events. These are explained in the documentation on working with lists of data, so I recommend reading that. For example, when a child node (such as a chat message) is added to the list, you can get just a snapshot of that specific message with onChildAdded.
